# Cannot access built-in webcam Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to access my laptop webcam and from what I have seen, I need to use the cv2 package. I downloaded it from [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python/3.2.0.7) but the contents of the file seem to be missing a lot of content as it only has `__init__.py`, `cv2.cp36-win32.pyd`, and `opencv_ffmpeg320.dll`. So whenever I try use things such as `VideoCapture` and `imwrite`, it says it cannot find a reference to them.

When I run the application, I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RedCode/PycharmProjects/FunApps/ImageFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Users\RedCode\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I have got the numpy package installed and imported but it didn't fix the issue so I'm guessing that's not the actual cause of the problem, so I'm certain it must have something to do with the cv2 package.

The code I'm using right now is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

I'm also using Python 3.6 and Windows 10 if that helps with anything.

How can I get my application to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can solve your problem by using the following command:

```
pip install -U numpy
```

Check existing package:

```
pip show numpy
```

And upgrade it via:

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

Check the path if you still got error:

```
> import numpy
> print numpy.__path__
```

Answer (score 0):

You must install the latest version of numpy. Use the command `pip install numpy --upgrade` or you can just download the wheel file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Just check for your python version and platform and download the necessary wheel file. Next use pip to install the wheel file.